# can't make googlemaps search box to work

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have tried and tried but I can't make search box to work.
Don't see/understand where is the error.

I'm develloping my own map with google API and I would like to add a Google Map Search Box but can't find a way to succeed even after reading carefully the Google Map API.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
  1: {
    icon: 'images/pin_green.png',
  },
  0: {
    icon: 'images/pin_red.png',
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.72529919849261, -9.150065436059549),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("map_process.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var timeStamp = markers[i].getAttribute("timeStamp");
      var rate = markers[i].getAttribute("rate");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = '<p>'+ timeStamp + '</p>';
      var icon = customIcons[rate] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });

// Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (
document.getElementById('pac-input'));
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
/** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
(input));

// Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
// pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
  marker.setMap(null);
}

// For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
markers = [];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var place = null;
var viewport = null;
for (var i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
  var image = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
  };

  // Create a marker for each place.
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  viewport = place.geometry.viewport;
  markers.push(marker);

  bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
}
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
});

// Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
// current map's viewport.
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
var bounds = map.getBounds();
searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
});

}


function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

</script>

</head>
<body onload="load()">
  <input id="pac-input"></input>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: and what exactly is the problem / question?

Comment: you also tagged as php but there isn't any code to support the question. Good luck in debug.

Comment: Incidentally - you are missing the opening html tag. Read the errors in the console too

Comment: @RamRaider the search box fires places but the map doe no go to the desire place. If i put an address the map does not move.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks. Edited and corrected.

Comment: check your developer console and if this is related to PHP or you're using a db, check for errors in there also.

Comment: @RamRaider <html> added. You can check code working here http://www.marianamegre.com/map/

Comment: I copied your code and other than errors because it could not find `map_process.php` and thus subsequently errors about xml it seems to work. Incidentally I see the same error on your site about xml - you need to put some error checking into your php and js routines perhaps. The simplest solution to ensure the map / search goes where you want I think might be to declare `var markers=[];` outwith the other code as a global

Comment: yep, worked fine for me too. as per what @RamRaider said.

Comment: @RamRaider map_process.php gets markers from database, and that is working (not on site because it is not connected to a database) but the problem lies on the search box. Put and address and see what happens.
Also, xml works fine when i try it.

Comment: @RamRaider: The `<html>` tag is optional but **now** that it has been added in the wrong place, the markup has become (more) broken.

Comment: @NisseEngström <html> removed.

Comment: wild guess... try using form tags `<form>
  <input id="pac-input">
</form>` *very* wild, but doubt it.

Comment: @RamRaider "declare var markers=[]; outwith the other code as a global" - can you explain it better please?

Comment: @Fred-ii- <form> <input id="pac-input"> </form> does not work.

Comment: JS developer console shows `TypeError: xml is null` and `load/<()
downloadUrl/request.onreadystatechange()` and `ReferenceError: markers is not defined`

Comment: The problem (as pmcmf stated) is that the markers array is not defined.  Define it in the global context and the SearchBox works.

Comment: @geocodezip "Define it in the global context and the SearchBox works." - know you got me lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (as RamRaider stated) is that the markers array is not defined. Define it in the global context and the SearchBox works.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6e13b0yo/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var customIcons = {
  1: {
    icon: 'images/pin_green.png',
  },
  0: {
    icon: 'images/pin_red.png',
  }
};
var markers = [];

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.72529919849261, -9.150065436059549),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
  downloadUrl("map_process.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var timeStamp = markers[i].getAttribute("timeStamp");
      var rate = markers[i].getAttribute("rate");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
        parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = '<p>' + timeStamp + '</p>';
      var icon = customIcons[rate] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */ (
    document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
    (input));

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var place = null;
    var viewport = null;
    for (var i = 0; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      viewport = place.geometry.viewport;
      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });

}


function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", load);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" />
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
```

Comment: erm, think it was me that suggested to define the variable in the global scope '-)

Comment: @RamRaider, sorry, fixed the attribution.

Comment: :) it's ok @geocodezip - all's well that ends well!

Answer (score 0):

For my test I found that by adding `var markers=[];` before you declare `function main()` resolved many of the errors I saw in the console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var markers=[];
..... etc with your code as before
```

Then, within the callback you could probably remove the `var` from `var markers=xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");`
I'm not saying this is the final solution to the problem, this was more an observation and fix ~ it did however mean that when I typed in a location the map changed and displayed that location without needing the ajax / db lookup.